# Interwoven Teamsite Download and Installation links

Tags: teamsite, interwoven

I need to install interwoven Teamsite Content Center Professional on my system, I can't find any web address online where I can download the exe. I even tried logging in it online at 
http://teamsite.partners.org/
But the link does not work. Please if anyone has solution to this, please answer asap.
Thanks
Aysha

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about downloading it without procurement then there is no direct link to Teamsite on your local system as it is not open source. You would have to contact Autonomy who will provide you assistence with procuring the software.

If you have alerady purchased the software,please go to the below mentioned link if you aleardy have purchased the software.

https://support.interwoven.com/supportloginau.asp

[teamsite](/questions/tagged/teamsite) [interwoven](/questions/tagged/interwoven)

Answer (score 0):

All what You need, You can find on the [Interwoven support page](http://support.interwoven.com). You will find there all necessary files and pdf's with installation guides and other important things. HP have also very good community [link](https://community.dev.hp.com/). So if You will have any problems with installation I'm pretty sure they will help You.